# Jquery: Get the ids of all the check values in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jquery to add a new checkbox when I click an option from an existing checkbox.

Next I add an id in this checkbox and I  get it's value through a new jquery. I want to create a new jquery to get the ids of ALL the extended checked ids.

My current html code is:

```
<div id="div_id_diag-diagnosis_option" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_diag-diagnosis_option_0" class="control-label col-md-3 requiredField">Option<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="controls col-md-8">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_1" value="b">b</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_2" value="a">a</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="diag-diagnosis_option" id="id_diag-diagnosis_option_3" value="c">c</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery to add the checkbox is:

```
$("input[name='diag-diagnosis_option']").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option);
        $(this).parent().append("<a href='#'>here</a>");
    } else if ($this.siblings('a').length) {
        $this.siblings('a').remove();
    }
});
```

The jquery to get the value of the new checkbox is the one below:

```
    $(document).on('change', '#extended', function () {
    var option = $(this).val();
    //alert(option);
});
```

The jquery to get the ids of all the extended checked checkboxes is the one below but it's not working.

```
var selected = [];
$(document).on('each', '#extended input:checked', function () {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    alert(selected);
});
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zinonas/Luskw0nu/).

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for iterating over checkboxes. You are trying to use `each` as an event. However each is jquery method and not even associated to element. and correct syntax to use it is:

```
var selected = [];
$('#extended input:checked').each(function () {
  selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
  alert(selected);
});
```

However you can achieve this in cleaner way using `.map()` along with `.get()` to achieve this:

```
var selected = $('#extended input:checked').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('name');
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to stored all the checked values not only the one selected at the moment.

Comment: `#extended` used on multiple elements, use class instead.

Comment: @zinon: you should write the snippet in change event for that.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: is it?? did not see that coming

Comment: Can you give me a demo please using it?

Comment: @zinon:you already have change event. write the above code in it

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I did it but I don't get the values. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/zinonas/Luskw0nu/

Comment: @zinon: you should not be duplicating IDs. here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0nszt1of/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

As you append checkboxes dynamically , you should add values at there change event .. also you have dynamic checkboxes with same id .. you should use class instead of id that is not permitted

Do it as-

```
var selected = [];
$("input[name='diag-diagnosis_option']").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var option = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().append('<label><input type="checkbox" class="extended" 
                               name="extended" value=' + escape($(this).attr('value')) + '>
                               Extended</label>');

    } else if ($this.siblings('label').length) {

        $this.siblings('label').remove();

    }
});


$(document).on('change', '.extended', function () {
    var option = $(this).val(); // or attr('name');
    selected.push(option);
    alert(selected);
});
```

**LIVE** https://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/wt9btcb0/

Comment: Yes you are right! But also it's not working either.